# Difference between a non-linear neuron vs non-linear activation function

Tags: neural-networks

I need to know the difference between a non-linear neuron vs non-linear  activation function

AND

linear neuron vs linear activation function.

Answer (score 3):

A neurons behaviour is made up of two sections:

1. a weighted sum of inputs
2. an activation function

The weighted sum of inputs is used by the activation function to produce the output of the neuron.

As the weighted sum of inputs is a linear operation, whether or not the neuron is linear or non-linear is **determined by the activation function**.

Therefore there is no difference between a non-linear neuron and a non-linear activation function. The same is true for linear neuron and linear activation function.